# Could someone compare basic anonymity vs basic computer hacker anonymity?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, tor, black-hat

So, let's say one just doesn't want the government/corporations to know what they are doing online. Let's say, for example, that they just don't trust the NSA, FBI, Google, etc.

So what are the steps it would take to anonymize someone of each one: normal person and then a black hat hacker who isn't severe. Maybe they are at a basic level where the black hat hacker just hacks FB accounts and looks at data on people's computers. The grey hat would just be grey hat for the same thing, just trying to justify it more. Then you have, let's just say a pen tester.

I'm not looking at the extreme revolutionary scenario, where one would be plotting to overthrow the government because that's an insane level of hacker.

Comment: "(comparing of those two separately would be great if you want to elaborate further)" - this should probably be a separate question. on Stack Exchange (welcome, by the way!) we like to have only one actual question per site question.

Comment: while you've done a great job breaking down a "scale" of anonymity needs, it's still not specific enough to say "a normal person". give a _specific_ scenario, a specific threat, something more detailed.

Comment: By "normal person" I don't mean that literally. I mean, someone who just doesn't want government or business monitoring their internet browsing.

Comment: And I would want to compare that to a grey hat hacker since that's more specific.